# How to create an exit message

Tags: ruby, error-handling, exit

Is there a one line function call that quits the program and displays a message? I know in Perl it's as simple as:

```
die("Message goes here")
```

I'm tired of typing this:

```
puts "Message goes here"
exit
```

Comment: A small comment, your `puts` writes to stdout, whereas `die` writes to stderr, so: `$stderr.puts "Message goes here"`.

Comment: I know that this wasn't an answer, but it answered my question, thanks

Comment: Just for the reference, in Python it is `sys.exit("Message goes to stderr")`.

Answer (score 371, accepted):

The `abort` function does this. For example:

```
abort("Message goes here")
```

Note: the `abort` message will be written to `STDERR` as opposed to `puts` which will write to `STDOUT`.

Comment: Wow!  Nice find!  Too bad they didn't just overload exit with this functionality....

Comment: Note, abort exits the program with a status of false which represents a failure. exit by default exits with a status of true representing success. Make sure you use the right one for the situation.

Comment: re. Mike Stone's comment, it sometimes looks as though Ruby was written by a team of people who had no communication with one another, doesn't it? (Still, it's so easy to program in it.)

Answer (score 24):

If you want to denote an actual error in your code, you could raise a `RuntimeError` exception:

```
raise RuntimeError, 'Message goes here'
```

This will print a stacktrace, the type of the exception being raised and the message that you provided. Depending on your users, a stacktrace might be too scary, and the actual message might get lost in the noise. On the other hand, if you die because of an actual error, a stacktrace will give you additional information for debugging.

Comment: You don't need to mention RuntimeError to raise one (it's the default kind of exception raised) so the following code will suffice:

    raise 'Message goes here'

Comment: sunaku - while your comment is perfectly valid, I often found that being more explicit can be useful, in particular for other people reading the code lateron.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of such a function, but it would be trivial enough to implement...

```
def die(msg)
  puts msg
  exit
end
```

Then, if this is defined in some .rb file that you include in all your scripts, you are golden.... just because it's not built in doesn't mean you can't do it yourself ;-)

Comment: Turns out the 'abort' function does it (see my answer below)

Comment: Why write code when the abort function does it for you?

Comment: @ChrisBunch This is **not** the same as the abort function:

`exit` defaults to returning as if it has succeeded. `abort` returns a failure. `exit 1` will return a failure as well.