# Rails equivalent to php die()?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

Is there an equivalent in Rails to PHP's `die()`?

I have a case where it would make my controller code a little cleaner to set it up in a way that would sometimes call render twice, unless there is a die() that is.

Comment: have you tried doing a `return` ? (with no args)

Comment: @Andrei S, That would work but I have several actions that use a common resond method, and I just want to call "die" once in the common respond method.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
abort("Message goes here")
```

See: [How to create an exit message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29539/ruby-exit-message)

Comment: A better answer is `render :text => "Message goes here"`

Comment: I won't pretend to be a Ruby expert, but according to [this article](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) it seems that `render` is inappropriate as an equivalent to PHP's `die()` because execution continues after `render` is called.

Answer (score 1):

A direct mapping of PHP's `die()` in Ruby would be [Kernel::exit()](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001444)

Comment: Er, it really isn't. `Kernel::exit()` raises a SystemExit exception, an exception which can be caught and ignored. While PHP's `die()` does  permit destructors to run, this is a different circumstance and calling it a direct mapping is wholly inaccurate.