# abort in rails loop function

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've got a function in my rails controller (I know, not the rails way, but I find it easier to write in the controller when I have something big like this and then move to the model).

I have an error in a array that I'm looping through, unfortunately, the error is being added somewhere in the loop. It is a big array with lots of properties, and I'm trying to figure out where the error is being caused.

I think I can isolate which object in the array is causing the error, but I can't get it to print.

Aparently ruby has an

```
abort('message')
```

function, but that returns an error in rails.

`return render` isn't working, it gives me an error that `render and/or redirect is being called multiple times`. How can I do a php type `die` in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29539/ruby-exit-message) makes an excellent suggestion.

```
raise RuntimeError, 'Message goes here'
```

In the `'Message goes here'` section you could even add in the array element:

```
array.each do |array_element|
     <logic>
     raise RuntimeError, "#{array_element.inspect}; Message goes here"
end
```